# Port forwarding between two routers?

Tags: networking

I have an ipcamera, router_1 and router_2.

The connection is like:

ipcamera(192.168.1.100)->router_1(192.168.1.1)->router_2(192.168.0.1).

Router_1's WAN port is connected to router_2's LAN port.
My laptop is connected to router_2.
How can I set the port forwarding so that I can access my ipcamrea?

Comment: Is your laptop connected to the second router's LAN port or the WAN port?

Comment: Connected to the lan port

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop and your R1's WAN interface is on the same LAN, so we can leave R2 aside. I am assuming that your IPCam provides some kind of WEB interface to see what is happening and I am assuming it is running on port 80. You will need to substitute it to correct number if that is not the case.

If my assumptions are correct, then you will need to enable port forwarding in the first router. You will have to forward requests to port 80 to the IP address of the ipcam (192.168.1.100:80)

And for future reference - this is programming site, so questions like this should go to the sister site of SO called SuperUser